# Passing data with a delegate from a closure

Tags: delegates, closures, swift4, mklocalsearch

I have two view controllers and I am trying to pass data from one to the other.  The data is returned from an MKLocalSearch closure.  But I cannot seem to get my delegate method to run.  I hope that someone can shed some light on this?  I mocked up a smaller version of what I'm trying to do. Also, I don't use storyboards.  I code up everything. Here is the code...

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

protocol SendDataDelegate {
    func sendData(data: String)
}

class OneViewController: UIViewController {

var delegate: SendDataDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    doSearch() { coord in
        if let coord = coord {
            //When the execution gets here, coord does have
            //the values to be sent to the nexr view controller.
            self.delegate?.sendData(data: "\(coord)")
            let twoViewController = TwoViewController()
            self.present(twoViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

func doSearch(completion: @escaping (CLLocationCoordinate2D?) -> Void) {

    var coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()

    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "New York"

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

    search.start(completionHandler: {(response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error occured in search:\(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else if response!.mapItems.count == 0 {
            print("No matches found")
        } else {
            print("Matches found")

            coord = response?.mapItems[0].placemark.coordinate
        }
        completion(coord)
    })
  }
}

import UIKit

class TwoViewController: UIViewController, SendDataDelegate {

var myData: String = ""
var oneViewController = OneViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    oneViewController.delegate = self
}

func sendData(data: String) {
    myData = data
    print ("myData: \(myData)")
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `TwoViewController`, you have a property holding **another** instance of `OneViewController` and setting the delegate of it to `self`.

So, each time you create an instance of `TwoViewController`, a new instance of `OneViewController` is created, but none of them are actually the one in due of showing the actual view of `OneViewController`.

In your case, delegate pattern is not appropriate and you should better call the method of `TwoViewController` directly:

```
class OneViewController: UIViewController {

    //no need to have a delegate

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        doSearch() { coord in
            if let coord = coord {
                //When the execution gets here, coord does have
                //the values to be sent to the nexr view controller.
                let twoViewController = TwoViewController()
                twoViewController.sendData(data: "\(coord)")
                self.present(twoViewController, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

    //...    
}

class TwoViewController: UIViewController {

    var myData: String = ""
    //Creating a new instance of `OneViewController` has no meaning.

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Useless to set the delegate of newly created `OneViewController`.
    }

    func sendData(data: String) {
        myData = data
        print ("myData: \(myData)")
    }

}
```

If you have any reason to have a property `oneViewController` in `TwoViewController`, please explain why. Your current code explains nothing.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the reference.  I took a break.  Came back and saw the erroneous reference.  I now have the delegation pattern working correctly!  Thanks.